# PHP MySQLi Insert Query Error - Server Has Gone Away

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On trying to insert array of records, I am getting errors :
1. MySQL server has gone away
2. Error reading result set's header

Following are the details:

```
// DB2
$host1 = 'localhost';
$user1 = 'root';
$pass1 = '';
$db1   = 'my_db';
$conn1 = mysqli_connect($host1, $user1, $pass1, $db1);

....
...
...
...

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($countryArr); die;
```

$countryArr result :
[image]

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `cities` (`country_id`, `city`, `soft_delete`, `date_added`) VALUES " . implode(',', $countryArr);
mysqli_query($conn1, $query);
```

Error : 
[image]

Comment: How many records are to be inserted? `MySQL server has gone away` is because php looses connection with mysql

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Around 50000 records are to be inserted.

Comment: change setting in php.ini  max_execution_time = 0 (or  3600000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

```
set_time_limit(0); // this will remove the time limit if any.
```

**Step 2:**

Also check ping to keep the connection alive, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

**Step 3**

Try executing the inserts in batches. i.e Batch of 500 statements.

Comment: @KunwarbirS. glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL server has gone away` may be due to exceeding limit on mysql packet size.
Check MySQL variable `max_allowed_packet` and try to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query takes 13+ seconds to execute while your mysql server is set to kill a connection after a number of seconds smaller than 13.

Change this row in your mysql configuration file (usually located in /etc/mysql)

```
wait_timeout=15 //any reasonable amount of time more than 13 seconds for your example
```

PS: you might also need to change the maximum number of connections allowed to reflect the change in the wait_time. to do that, change these 2 rows in mysql configuration file.

```
max_connections=90
max_user_connections=60
```

Changing the max connections could be necessary, depending on the activity of your server. For example, if your timeout is 5 and your max connections is 30, and assuming all queries are long quires taking exactly 5 seconds to process, then your server can only serve 6 connections at a time.

Now assuming you change the timeout to 15 and the quires take 15, your server will only be able to serve 2 connections.

Hope that helps!